# Equation of 1 22 333 4444 55555 sequence?

Tags: sequence, formula, equation

i need to find 1 22 333 sequence formula/equation.

I write this code for getting number like that but i need to find equation of this sequence

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(i);
    }

    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

With this code I get this results

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

Also Latex code line should works for me to.

I mean equation somethings like this for example:

[image: example equation]

Comment: What is the term just after 9...9?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000461

Comment: @AlexK. this link has no equation at all. I updated my question. See the picture for example equation.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qful6omg6jw66mu/2016-05-09%2012_59_40-%E2%80%AAHostMath%20-%20Online%20LaTeX%20formula%20editor%20and%20browser-based%20math%20equation%20editor.png?dl=0

Comment: @CherryDT Yeah something like that

Comment: OK; the linked formula already applies to your problem with 1<=n<=9.

Comment: @CherryDT Are you sure? I applied into my code and its giving me 9, 90, ...., 900000000

Comment: This is not the way the formula works, it's a formula to calculate each individual element... Maybe I misunderstood you? I mean, to calculate the 3rd element (n=3), the right part of the equation would unroll to 3*10^0+3*10^1+3*10^2, i.e. 3*1+3*10+3*100, i.e. 3+30+300, i.e. 333.

Answer (score 5):

From the sum of a *geometric progression*, the value of the (n)th term is

`n*(power(10, n) - 1)/9`

where `power(a, b)` raises `a` to the `b`th power.

Answer (score 0):

The number *a*(*n*) that consists of *n* concatenated to itself *n* times is [image], where *D*(*n*) is the number of digits of *n*. This is a well-known [Smarandache Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmarandacheSequences.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sn= 1/1458 * ((18n−2)10^(n+1)−81n^2−81n+20)

The above formula is correct for the scenario where the nth term of the series is n multiplied by a number comprised of n ones. So the tenth term is not ten zeroes, it's 10(1111111111)
then 11(11111111111)
etc..