# Concatenate integers in a list and print it, without using a python for loop

Tags: python

I had a good go at this challenge question:

[image]

I thought I had been quite clever doing it in two lines (they give you the first line), but it doesn't work as I am using 2 for loops.

```
for i in range(1,int(input())): #More than 2 lines will result in 0 score. Do not leave a blank line also
    [print(([i]*i)[index],end = "\n" if index == (len([i] * i)-1) else '') for index,x in enumerate([i] * i)]
```

I must bravely admit defeat, but am intrigued how to do it in 2 lines, and only the one for loop...

Comment: `for i in range(1, int(input())): print(str(i)*i)`

Comment: No string operations allowed ;-).  And not allowed to use another for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113988/9225671) it is called "sum of a geometric progression"; after googling a bit more, this kind of number/sequence seems to be known as one kind of [Smarandache Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmarandacheSequences.html).

You can try this:

```
for i in range(1, int(input())):
    print(int(i * ((10**i) - 1) / 9))
```

It is a confusing one liner, but it seems to work.

Comment: @smackenzie I found the answer by googling `1 22 333 4444`; sometimes life is simple

Comment: The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (oeis.org) is a good tool for finding generating functions (and other details) of sequences given a few example terms.

Comment: @jasonharper you are right, that is a good tool; here is a search for this case http://oeis.org/search?q=1+22+333+4444

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i in range(1, int(input('Number of iterations: '))):
    print(str(i)*i)
```

Sample output:

```py
>>> for i in range(1, int(input('Number of iterations: '))):
        print(str(i)*i)

Number of iterations: 10
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
```

Comment: Not allowed to use string operations ;-)

Comment: Damn. That almost worked! I should have read the question properly.

Comment: Hmm. This almost works: ```for i in range(1, int(input('Number of iterations: '))):
 print([i]*i)

Number of iterations: 3
[1]
[2, 2]```

Answer (score 1):

This would also be an acceptable an

```
for i in range(1, input()):
print(((10 ** i - 1) // 9) * i)
```

Comment: Oops, this one was answered before I posted mine

Answer (score 0):

Is this acceptable:

```
a = 9
print(*[str(i)*i for i in range(1, a)], sep='\n')

1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, int(input('Number of iterations: '))):
    print i * sum([pow(10, j) for j in range(i)])
```

The inner for is not a loop, it's a list comprehension.

Comment: You are technically correct (which is the best kind of correct), but I doubt the challenge had this in mind when making the restrictions.